# Merge / Group sub level multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having issues doing some basic math with my arrays; the array format I have is this:

```
Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => 
[p_type] => 
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amountt] => 
)
Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => 
[p_type] => Initial
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] => 2.22)

Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => 
[p_type] => Shipping
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] =>0.22
)

Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => shipping_add
[p_type] => 
[fees] => 
[sku] => 412
[amount] => 0.50 )

Array
(
[id] => 325
[type] => comms
[p_type] => 
[fees] => 1.00
[sku] => 412
[amount] => 1.22
)
```

As you can see, the ID is the same, so I'd like to loop through each item with the same ID, to calculate the total sum of `[amount] + [fees]` and to be able to display it later.

I've tried to do a basic means of calculating via another array:

```
$data = array($total, $fees, $comms);
$data = array("a" => $total, "b" => $fees, "c" => $comms);
$data = array_sum($data);
```

However that doesn't really give me the correct method.

Comment: What will be your expected output ?

Comment: Hi, please see this answer, this is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475469/how-to-format-data-in-specific-way-using-html-and-php/29476267#29476267

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($myArray as $key=>$value){
     if (!isset($result[$myArray[$key]['id']]['amount'])) $result[$myArray[$key]['id']]['amount'] = 0;
     if (!isset($result[$myArray[$key]['id']]['fees'])) $result[$myArray[$key]['id']]['fees'] = 0;

     $result[$myArray[$key]['id']]['amount'] += $myArray[$key]['amount']; 
     $result[$myArray[$key]['id']]['fees'] += $myArray[$key]['fees'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```